# Routines backup in Percona xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I am using Percona xtrabackup for creating backup of mysql server. Does backup file includes all the procedures, functions and triggers ? Does it get restored when i restore it ?

Answer (score 4):

Procedures, functions are stored in `mysql` database, triggers in  respective database directories. XtraBackup makes a copy of all of that.

It however doesn't make a copy of MySQL config file (`/etc/my.cnf`) you should take care of it.